# How do you call a column that refers to a column in the same table?

Tags: database-design, terminology

There is a term that identifies a table column that refers to a column in another table. That is the term "foreign key".

Is there a term that identifies a table column that refers to a column in the same table?

An example of such column is the "item_parent" column which refers to the "item_id" column in the following table:
items(item_id, item_parent);

Comment: it's called 'self-referential'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In docs for [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx) these references are called "self-references".

Answer (score 2):

Tables of this type are generally referred to as "self-referencing".

I'm not aware of a specific term for columns involved in a self-referencing foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "self-referencing", there's the term "reflexive relationship".

For a reference in the MSDN, [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y43441tz(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the -false- idea that "foreign keys" must necessarily reference *other* tables (and that there therefore must exist some other term for a foreign key that references the very same table) ?

Comment: I got that idea from a Wikipedia article called "Foreign Key" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key